# $\sin^2 x \cos^2 x + \sin x \cos x -1 = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

> $\sin^2 x \cos^2 x +  \sin x \cos x -1 = 0$

Attempt:

$\sin^2 2x + 2\sin 2x -4 = 0 \\ \implies \sin 2x= \sqrt 5 - 1$

Now, using the formula $\sin 2 x = \dfrac {2\tan x}{1+\tan^2x}$, I couldn't express the answer in terms of $\tan()$

The answer given is in terms of tan. How do I express it in that way?

Comment: $$\sqrt5-1>1$$ right?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Oh, so it has no real solution?

Comment: In real trigonometry, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

Observe the roots of $t^2+2t-4=0$ are $-1\pm\sqrt 5$ (no denominator), and their absolute values are greater than $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to continue this problem lies in realizing that since $\sqrt{5}\pm1>1$, we must have that $x\not\in\mathbb{R}$.

You can begin looking for complex solutions to this problem by utilizing the fact that $$\sin2x=\frac{e^{2ix}-e^{-2ix}}{2i}$$
and solving yet another quadratic equation in terms of a complex exponential.

Applying the complex logarithm $$\log z=\log |z|+i\mathrm{Arg}z$$ will give you your solutions.